# structured streaming writing and reading from same csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

in my job i am writing stream to a CSV file, immediately after that i want to read from the stream. But my readstream is failing as

"JVM method execution failed: Nonstatic method schema failed for class 370 when called with 1 arguments "

when running in standalone cluster, i can see the write stream has created some crc files and blank csv file.

```
# write stream
spark.writestream().format("csv").option("path","myfile.csv").start()

#read stream 
spark.readStream().schema(myschema).Csv("myfile.csv")
```

Comment: Hi, I'm somewhat new to Spark Streaming, but I would expect your writestream to be writing from an object of some kind (eg Dataframe).  like `myDF.writeStream.etc` . Also, I think you can skip the `()` after `readStream`

Comment: yes my writestream is writing staging data and i want my readstream to start reading fro staged data. but it fails with above message

Comment: So your staging data/dataframe is named `spark`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using JSON format schema to read call, whereas it expected DDL format schema